# Applications of Baire's theorem on functions of first class

Tags: set-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, measure-theory, limits-and-convergence, descriptive-set-theory

I found the following theorem on page 32 of John Oxtoby's *Measure and Category*.

> **Theorem 7.3.** If $f$ can be represented as the limit of an everywhere convergent sequence of continuous functions, then $f$ is continuous except at a set of points of first category.

It was said to have many applications. The two applications mentioned are:

1. The sum of a trigonometric series can not converge pointwise to a function discontinuous on a set of second category. I imagine this is useful in harmonic analysis, though I am not well-read in this area.
2. (My favorite.) The derivative of a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ can not be discontinuous on a nonmeagre set. This follows from viewing the derivative as the pointwise limit of continuous functions

\begin{equation}
f^{\prime}(x)= \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n, \quad  f_n:= \frac{f(x+1 / n)-f(x)}{1 / n}.
\end{equation}

Are there any other nice applications of this theorem? I particularly like the second because functions like
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 
  x^2 \sin(1/x) &\mbox{if } x \neq 0 \\
0 & \mbox{if } x=0 
\end{cases}.
$$
suggest that differentiable functions can have very pathological derivatives, but this theorem puts substantial constraints on the derivatives of real-valued functions in the simplest way I've seen.

Comment: A Riemann integrable function, which is continuous "Lebesgue almost everywhere" (and hence continuous on a dense set), is also continuous "Baire almost everywhere". Actually, a stronger "almost everywhere" result holds -- see the last paragraph [of this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/870108/13130).

Comment: It seems like the 2nd application doesn’t follow from the theorem you quote, but rather from the preceding theorem in the text.

Comment: @MonroeEskew Thank you for the correction. I have edited the question.

Comment: Some remarkable properties of the Pompeiu derivatives are proven by the Baire'e theorem, both in the real line and in function spaces. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pompeiu_derivative